# How to apply different color to different rows in HTML using css [not to alternate rows , but any color to any row]

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: As shown in the image i want to apply different color to different rows and columns, not only to alternate ones]

As shown in the image i want to apply different color to different rows and columns, not only to alternate ones

Comment: Have you tried anything ? _Too broad!_

Comment: You might need to add a `class` to each row and do the styling as necessary.

Comment: @Rayon yeas, applying color to alternate rows. Will upload the code in few minutres

Comment: I doubt if it can done using only css

Comment: @user2181397 Is their any way using JS

Answer (score 1):

Check below examples.

1. Add a `class` to required row and apply styles as required.
2. Use `nth-child` selector.

**Using `class`**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
tr.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
tr.green {
  background-color: green;
}
tr.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
tr.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="yellow">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="red">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="green">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blue">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Using `nth-child`**

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
tr:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
}
tr:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: will try it on rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

You can define class for every row with different color or you  can user
:nth-child(n) pseudo class for every row

Comment: instead of "nth" , is their any way to write "1st child" "2nd child" "3rd child" and so

Comment: @Yashika: your can write tr:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(2), tr:nth-child(3)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, create a random function which assigns random color to each row of the table.

Checkout a sample of that

```js
function init(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('trentries');
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){  
      getRandomColor(elements[i]);
    }
  }

function getRandomColor(element) {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
  element.style.background = color;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <table class='table'>
    <tr class='head'>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    <tr>
    <tr class='trentries'>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='trentries'>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='trentries'>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='trentries'>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
      <td class='entries'>a</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<body>
```